# Get the persons, who are in both sets

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have a question I don't know how to ask right, so I start with the SQL Statement (Postgres):

```
SELECT pc.person_id
  FROM groups g
  LEFT OUTER JOIN group_clubs gc ON (gc.group_id = g.id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN person_club pc ON (gc.club_id = pc.club_id)
 WHERE g.id = 2
```

What I have:
A group, which has a criteria with club, a user has to be in.
This is split up into the `groups` table, the `group_clubs` table and the `person_club` table

What I want:
I want to get all persons, who are in ALL the clubs, connected to this group.
What I get:
I get all the persons, who are in at least one of the clubs.

I am stuck and got no idea, how to get the result, only I need to intersect the results, but I don't know how to do it now...?!?

**EDIT:**
To explain what I am looking for, here is a statement which does the same:

```
SELECT pc.person_id
  FROM person_club pc
 WHERE pc.club_id IN (
    SELECT gc.club_id
      FROM group_clubs gc
      WHERE gc.group_id = 2
 );
```

What I want is:

```
SELECT pc.person_id
  FROM person_club pc
 WHERE pc.club_id IN ALL(
     SELECT gc.club_id
       FROM group_clubs gc
      WHERE gc.group_id = 2
);
```

The person should be **IN ALL** of the group_clubs listed by this statement!

Comment: In oracle, there is a keyword called INTERSECT, so if that is standard, postresql might have the same.  Query A INTERSECT Query B will only return the values that are in both Queries.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek: Postgres does support the standard `INTERSECT` operator.

Comment: intersect only works inbetween queries in postgres. And I have no two queries, because i might need an interesection of 12 clubs, since there can be 12 clubs as criterias for this group.

Comment: I added some more explaination to the problem!

Comment: I added the relational-division tag. This problem is a typical example of reldiv. If you brouse the `related` questions on the right here, you will probably find what you are looking for. I'd suggest a _double negation_ kind of query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer thanks to a colleague:

```
SELECT pc.person_id
  FROM person_club_data pc
  INNER JOIN group_clubs gc ON (gc.club_id = pc.club_id)
 WHERE gc.group_id = 2
 GROUP BY pc.person_id
 HAVING COUNT(pc.person_id) >= (
     SELECT COUNT(gc.club_id)
       FROM group_clubs gc2
      WHERE gc2.group_id = 2
 )
```

I select the persons, and the persons who occur exactly as often as group_clubs rows can be found for group 2 and who are connected to this group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT pc.person_id
  FROM groups g
  INNER JOIN group_clubs gc ON (gc.group_id = g.id)
  INNER JOIN person_club pc ON (gc.club_id = pc.club_id)
 WHERE g.id = 2
```

I don't think you need the last line (the WHERE clause) unless you meant to just retrieve one person.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no difference between INNER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN in this statement! I get exactly the same person_ids